# Scraping Airbnb with Scrapy, simply get the title of a page

Tags: scrapy

Very dumb question i wanted to learn a bit about web scraping, and start the [scrapy at glance tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) and i'm already stuck on the first step.

I wanted to apply the code they provide to try it on airbnb and scrape a normal announce ([like this one](https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/38940798))

Here is the code i use, i'm just trying to have the title of the announce in a .json, here is my code :

```py
import scrapy

class AirbnbSpyder(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'airbnbCrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.com', 'airbnb.fr']
    start_urls = ['https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/38940798']

    def parse(self, response):
        for room in response.css('div._5z4v7g'):
            yield {
                'title': room.css('h1._14i3z6h::text').get(),
            }
```

and run it with `scrapy runspider airbnb.py -o airbnb.json`

What i should have in my json is one object with title of the announce : Hypercentre /Ste Catherine - T3 + cour

I'm trying to use the same code provided in the scrapy doc, but it does not work, what i'm missing ?

I run the example code provided by scrapy and i'm able to scrape the quote website in the example

I've read sometime that this can happen depending on how the website is rendered. If it's not server-side i might use selenium with scrapy to simulate a browser ? Is it the case here ?

Answer (score 0):

what do you get when you run the spider? I ran pretty much exactly your code and got a csv with the title correctly, the only difference I see is that my class has spider spelled with an 'I' and not a 'Y'

```
import scrapy


class AirbnbCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'airbnb_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['airbnb.com', 'airbnb.fr']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/38940798?source_impression_id=p3_1591568412_tmhfLkpmkMtUrhEE&guests=1&adults=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for room in response.css('div._5z4v7g'):
            yield {
                'title': room.css('h1._14i3z6h::text').get(),
            }
```

Here is what I got from a json

```
[
{"title": "Hypercentre /Ste Catherine - T3 + cour"}
]
```

[My results from running spider in a csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c8Gy.png)

So it doesn't seem to be that the site is rendering the title server-side at least

Comment: I used 
```
scrapy runspider airbnb_crawler.py -o title.json
```
for the json and title.csv for the csv file